# Wasting memory size by python for test purpose

Tags: python, lambda

I have python program which works on `aws-lambda`.

It sometimes works and sometimes not (about one time in 20 times)

No error message, nor no signal.

So I guesss this is because of memory... maybe.

For testing purpose,

I want to make the program which wastes the memory on purpose.

I searched around but can't find the good sample or explanation.

Almost all samples are for `not wasting memory`

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Use "lingering large objects which are not released,
reference cycles within the code,
underlying libraries/C extensions leaking memory". A simple memory-leaking program - https://gist.github.com/waichee/b94eecfd57c6d68606c4be78e2317baa. Taken from https://zendesk.engineering/hunting-for-memory-leaks-in-python- applications-6824d0518774.

Comment: Thank you this script solves my problm.